# Ratchet IO Server suddenly stop working

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I am using `Ratchet` `Server`. I am running it using cron job. My Chat application is working fine. But after sometime `Rachet` stop working. When I recheck whether the process is running or not, I can see the process is still there, but the `Ratchet server` basically could not be `connected` to anymore.

Here is my code which running server:

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
new HttpServer(
    new WsServer(
        new AppServer()
    )
),
8082);
$server->run();
```

I database connection fails at some point which stops the server. Any possible solution of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `install Supervisord` service in your `Web Server` which actually `watch` your `Rachet Server`, If your `Rachet Server` stopped it will automatically start it again.

You can get `Supervisord` installation details from [here](http://supervisord.org/installing.html).

Comment: I have added a `cron job` which automatically kill the process after some hours and `Supervisord` automatically starts it so port remains open.

Comment: The issue is coming due to database. Database queries break the connection at some point.